# Ruby : How can I detect/intelligently guess the delimiter used in a CSV file?

Tags: ruby, delimiter, csv

I need to be able to figure out which delimiter is being used in a csv file (comma, space or semicolon) in my Ruby project. I know, there is a Sniffer class in Python in the csv module that can be used to guess a given file's delimiter. Is there anything similar to this in Ruby ? Any kind of help or idea is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Technically, only one of those is a CSV file...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like the py implementation just checks a few dialects: excel or excel_tab. So, a simple implementation of something that just checks for `","` or `"\t"` is:

```
COMMON_DELIMITERS = ['","',"\"\t\""].freeze

def sniff(path)
  first_line = File.open(path).first
  return unless first_line

  snif = {}
  COMMON_DELIMITERS.each do |delim| 
    snif[delim] = first_line.count(delim)
  end
  snif = snif.sort { |a,b| b[1]<=>a[1] }

  snif[0][0] if snif.size > 0
end
```

Note: that would return the full delimiter it finds, e.g. `","`, so to get `,` you could change the `snif[0][0]` to `snif[0][0][1]`.

Also, I'm using `count(delim)` because it is a little faster, but if you added a delimiter that is composed of two (or more) characters of the same type like `--`, then it would could each occurrence twice (or more) when weighing the type, so in that case, it may be better to use `scan(delim).length`.

Comment: Suggestion: `snif = COMMON_DELIMITERS.each_with_object({}) { |delim, h| h[delim] = first_line.count(delim) }.sort_by { |x| -x[1] }`

Answer (score 12):

Here is [Gary S. Weaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/178651/gary-s-weaver) answer as we are using it in production. Good solution that works well.

```
class ColSepSniffer
  NoColumnSeparatorFound = Class.new(StandardError)
  EmptyFile = Class.new(StandardError)

  COMMON_DELIMITERS = [
    '","',
    '"|"',
    '";"'
  ].freeze

  def initialize(path:)
    @path = path
  end

  def self.find(path)
    new(path: path).find
  end

  def find
    fail EmptyFile unless first

    if valid?
      delimiters[0][0][1]
    else
      fail NoColumnSeparatorFound
    end
  end

  private

  def valid?
    !delimiters.collect(&:last).reduce(:+).zero?
  end

  # delimiters #=> [["\"|\"", 54], ["\",\"", 0], ["\";\"", 0]]
  # delimiters[0] #=> ["\";\"", 54]
  # delimiters[0][0] #=> "\",\""
  # delimiters[0][0][1] #=> ";"
  def delimiters
    @delimiters ||= COMMON_DELIMITERS.inject({}, &count).sort(&most_found)
  end

  def most_found
    ->(a, b) { b[1] <=> a[1] }
  end

  def count
    ->(hash, delimiter) { hash[delimiter] = first.count(delimiter); hash }
  end

  def first
    @first ||= file.first
  end

  def file
    @file ||= File.open(@path)
  end
end
```

Spec

```
require "spec_helper"

describe ColSepSniffer do
  describe ".find" do
    subject(:find) { described_class.find(path) }

    let(:path) { "./spec/fixtures/google/products.csv" }

    context "when , delimiter" do
      it "returns separator" do
        expect(find).to eq(',')
      end
    end

    context "when ; delimiter" do
      let(:path) { "./spec/fixtures/google/products_with_semi_colon_seperator.csv" }

      it "returns separator" do
        expect(find).to eq(';')
      end
    end

    context "when | delimiter" do
      let(:path) { "./spec/fixtures/google/products_with_bar_seperator.csv" }

      it "returns separator" do
        expect(find).to eq('|')
      end
    end

    context "when empty file" do
      it "raises error" do
        expect(File).to receive(:open) { [] }
        expect { find }.to raise_error(described_class::EmptyFile)
      end
    end

    context "when no column separator is found" do
      it "raises error" do
        expect(File).to receive(:open) { [''] }
        expect { find }.to raise_error(described_class::NoColumnSeparatorFound)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Small bug in the code. This should be ```def self.find(path)
    new(path).find
  end```.

Comment: Updated answer to fix `self.find` issue

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any sniffer implementation in the CSV library included in Ruby 1.9. It will try to auto-discover the row separator, but the column separator is assumed to be a comma by default.

One idea would be to try parsing a sample number of rows (5% of total maybe?) using each of the possible separators. Whichever separator results in the same number of columns most consistently is probably the correct separator.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the [smarter_csv](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) gem with the `col_sep: :auto` option.

```rb
SmarterCSV.process(filename, {col_sep: :auto}) do |chunk|
end
```